# Using Fritz!Box 3490 to forward external traffic to internal servers

Tags: firewall, routing, ip, port-forwarding, ipv4

I have a Fritz!Box 3490 along with 5 usable external IPv4 addresses provided by our ISP. The Fritz!Box is to replace our existing DrayTek 2925.

One of five IP addresses is an MX; so we use that IP to send and receive emails on port 25 as well as allow mobile devices to connect remotely via port 443 for emails.

Using the Fritz!Box, I want to be able to forward traffic sent to the MX IP address to the local IP address of the Exchange server. The current IP address of the Exchange server is on a 10.1.1.0/24 range. The ISP says in order for the Fritz!Box to forward traffic sent to the external IP address, the Fritz!Box needs to know the public IPv4 subnet (which it does) but the Exchange server also needs the external IP address adding to the NIC.

Is this correct, and is this how the server should have been configured in the first place?

As for the other servers, the ISP says they too will need one of the external IP addresses adding to their NIC.

Is there a simpler approach to this, similar to how the DrayTek does it, where I can just tell it to forward traffic sent to EXTERNAL_IP:EXTERNAL_PORT to INTERNAL_IP:INTERNAL_PORT?

Comment: You're basically comparing NAT (port-forwarding) and direct routing. I don't know what a Fritz!box is capable of, nor what the rest of your network looks like, but direct routing _is_ how many servers are configured in the first place (with public subnets) and in various situations it _is_ 'the simpler approach'.

Answer (score 0):

The method described by your ISP is simpler for the router – essentially nothing more than *routing* between your subnet and the rest of the world. Assigning the server a public address directly is how servers are configured in many datacenters; it is the standard behavior for IPv6 and used to be standard for IPv4 too.

The method used by the DrayTek uses additional functionality – DNAT (port forwarding) – which might be present on a router or not. Even if present, it might not be hardware-accelerated to the same extent that pure routing is (due to requiring state lookups and actually rewriting the headers of every packet).

NAT may appear simpler if your usage of the public addresses is light, and it inherently allows sharing the same IP address between multiple servers (if you have more servers than addresses) – forward some ports to one, forward more ports to another, etc.

However, if you have enough addresses and/or a large amount of services, direct routing may end up being considerably simpler. It gives the server direct and full control of its own address; so after you've configured it *once* per server, you don't need to go back to the router adding more rules. Most home routers only allow configuring forward rules for TCP/UDP but not GRE nor ESP nor 6in4 nor other fancier protocols; direct routing works with everything by default.

Does Fritz!Box 3490 support DNAT configuration? Only partially. [According to this page](https://support.zen.co.uk/kb/Print11582.aspx) it's under "Permit Access → Port Sharing", but it does not allow you to select the *external* IP address. Whatever port rules you would add here, would probably apply to all addresses routed to you – or to all addresses assigned to the router itself (which I am guessing is limited to exactly one). The Linux-based core OS certainly supports matching on source address, but it's not exposed in the configuration UI for *some* reason; perhaps because it wouldn't be able to 
be hardware-accelerated, or it could have been just a deliberate decision. But the fact remains, if it's not available in the config UI, then the Fritz!Box DNAT won't fit your multiple-addresses use case.

Whereas, as I mentioned before, simple routing (the method your ISP wants) does not require any extra capabilities from the Fritz!Box – it literally has one job.